# can Bitcoin transactions are included in multiple blocks?

Tags: transactions, blockchain

Once the transactions published to blockchain and are included in blocks by miners. In that case there seems a high probability that a single transaction published can be included in multiple blocks created by different miners? is it true

Answer (score 1):

Yes, theoretically, 2 blocks could be mined at (almost) the same time.
And then, it's also possible that one transaction could be included in those 2 blocks.
But then, there are 2 blockchains, but only one of them (the longest one) will finally be accepted by the network.
So your transaction could be in 2 blocks, but only one time in a blockchain.

Comment: I see.. one more follow up question, if same set of transactions in multiple blocks are being mined by 10 miners at a given time and two nodes published their solution to blockchain and as you mentioned only one solution will be attached to the chain based on which solution has more length ; but what about other 8 miners ? they still continue to mine it or just stop mining once the solution block is published ?

Comment: There effort will be wasted after block is mined by one minner and it has become part of blockchain.